How to prove an eigenvector belongs to a span of an unstable matrix?
Suppose we have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a nonzero vector $p\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
If $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}A^kp\neq\textbf{0}$, then $A$ has an unstable eigenvector $v$ i.e., $Av=\lambda v$ with $|\lambda|\geq 1$, satisfying $v\in\text{span}\{p,Ap\dots,A^{n-1}p\}$.
This is a Lemma I read from a paper. But its author did not provide the proof. He mentioned a clue about using Caley-Hamilton theorem. I'm courious about the proof, please provide your opinions.
My intuition is that, at least we can conlude that $A$ is not strictly stable, otherwise its limit is zero. The subspace $\operatorname{Span}\{p,Ap,\ldots,A^{n-1}p\}$ (we denote it by $P$) is $A$-invariant, i.e., $AP\subset P$, then from this question: invariant space and eigenvector, I think I find my answer. I don't know if it is true.

Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that $V=\operatorname{span}\{p,Ap,\ldots,A^{n-1}p\}$ is an invariant subspace of $A$. The condition $\lim_{k\to\infty}A^kp\ne0$ guarantees that $(A|_V)^k$ does not converge to zero and hence $\rho(A|_V)\ge1$. Pick any eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ of $A|_V$ with $|\lambda|=\rho(A|_V)$. Now you are done.
